# Creating a data structure at specific memory location in C for ATSAME54 MCU

Tags: arrays, c, memory, struct

I'm working on an ATSAME54 Xplained Pro board that has SmartEEPROM and it's SEEPROM_ADDR= (0x44000000) and USER_PAGE_ADD= 00804000.

The energy meter is connected to one core and GSM is connected to another. I want to write all the types of data value received from the meter to this memory address so that the other core can read it.

Would somebody be able to help me figure out how to do this? How would I create a pointer to struct at a specific address?

The following is used only to write int value, but I want to create structure for all types of data and assign address to structure.

```
uint32_t *SmartEEPROM32     = (uint32_t *)SEEPROM_ADDR;
```

Comment: Change uint32_t* to struct foo*

Comment: I don,t understand it. Suppose i have a structure:                     struct object{ int obj1;   float obj2;  char obj3[10];};     then i have to assign SEEPROM_ADDR to this structure.  How i can assign it

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it

```
 typedef struct object{ int obj1; float obj2; char obj3[10];} foo;
 foo* SmartEEPROM32     = (foo *)SEEPROM_ADDR;
 SmartEEPROM32->obj2 = 2.5;
```

Note that the typedef is not required but saves typing `struct object` twice.

Answer (score 0):

Is this means structure address start from SEEPROM_ADDR= (0x44000000).?
I tried this but data not saves in that location.